# Settings SO_REUSEADDR in libpq

Tags: postgresql, tcp, libpq

Is there a way to instruct `libpq` library to set `SO_REUSEADDR` option for sockets it opens?

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR` makes sense with `bind()` which is a server-side call. Since libpq is client-side, what would be the use case for this option?

Comment: @DanielVérité If you open a lot of short-lived TCP connections on client side, you may end up having all ephemeral ports in TIME_WAIT. SO_REUSEADDR will allow you to reuse these ports.

Comment: Use an `LD_PRELOAD` wrapper library? It'd be good to be able to hook libpq's socket creation like you can in PgJDBC; maybe a patch to libpq to add that facility would go down well?